# How do I render the search form for a particular Apache SOLR search page on its own?

Tags: search

I have the [SOLR search module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) installed, and have set up a couple of different search pages.

I need to render the form for one of these pages on a separate page. I thought I could just piggy back off the default `search_form()`, but it doesn't work.

Using this code:

```
$build['search_form'] = drupal_get_form('search_form', 'directory/search', '', 'apachesolr_search');
```

The search form is displayed, and has the correct `action` property. But when the form is submitted, it just redirects to `directory/search`, without the keys in the URL (which are obviously required for the search).

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried using code similar to [search_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7), but I have the same problem as you have. Using `dpm($_POST)`, I noticed the page callback is called twice; when the page callback is called the second time, `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: Yeah it's a real head-scratcher :) I fancy the Solr module is getting involved early on and redirecting, but I can't find anything to suggest that in the module. The beautiful irony is I had fully faceted search set up in 15 minutes...and I've spent about 2.5 hours so far trying to work this one out!

Comment: I am testing the code with the User module, and I get the same behavior. (I am using the User module just because the search page for nodes is the default one.) I don't think it is because the ApacheSolr module; it must be because the Search module, or the way the page callback is defined.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno you're right, I put some debug code directly into the apachesolr_search module and it wasn't getting hit, so it looks like the core search module has a hand in this. I'm not sure where/why but luckily there's a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to use the search form in a page with a path different from the canonical one, using the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function code_testing_menu() {
  drupal_static_reset('search_get_info');
  $default_info = search_get_default_module_info();

  $items['test/search'] = array(
    'title' => 'User search test', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('code_testing_user_search_form'), 
    'access callback' => 'search_is_active', 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items["test/search/%menu_tail"] = array(
    'title' => 'User search test', 
    'load arguments' => array('%map', '%index'), 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('code_testing_user_search_form', 2), 
    'access callback' => '_search_menu_access', 
    'access arguments' => array('user'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
    'weight' => 0,
  );

  return $items;
}

function code_testing_user_search_form($form, &$form_state, $keys = '') {
  $info = FALSE;
  $keys = trim($keys);

  if (!$keys && !empty($_REQUEST['keys'])) {
    $keys = trim($_REQUEST['keys']);
  }

  $active_module_info = search_get_info();

  if (isset($active_module_info['user'])) {
    $info = $active_module_info['user'];
  }

  if (!$info) {
    form_set_error(NULL, t('Search is currently disabled.'), 'error');
    return $form;
  }

  $action = 'test/search';

  $form['#action'] = url($action);
  $form_state['action'] = $action;
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-form';

  $form['module'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => 'user',
  );

  $form['basic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
  );

  $form['basic']['keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Enter your keywords'), 
    '#default_value' => $keys, 
    '#size' => 40, 
    '#maxlength' => 255,
  );

  $form['basic']['processed_keys'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => '',
  );

  $form['basic']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );

  if (!empty($form_state['results'])) {
    $form['search_results'] = $form_state['results'];
  }

  return $form;
}

function code_testing_user_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $active_module_info = search_get_info();
  $conditions = NULL;
  $keys = $form_state['values']['keys'];

  if (!empty($active_module_info[$form_state['values']['module']])) {
    $info = $active_module_info[$form_state['values']['module']];

    if (isset($info['conditions_callback']) && function_exists($info['conditions_callback'])) {
      $conditions = call_user_func($info['conditions_callback'], $keys);
    }
    if ($keys || !empty($conditions)) {
      $form_state['results'] = search_data($keys, $info['module'], $conditions);
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I tried writing the page callback (`code_testing_user_search_view()`) for test/search, and test/search/%menu_tail basing on the [search_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/search_view/7) code, but it didn't work. I used `dpm($_POST, time());` in `code_testing_user_search_view()`, and I noticed the function was called twice, after the search form was submitted: In the first invocation, `$_POST` was populated with the expected values, while in the second invocation `$_POST` was an empty array. The code I used for `code_testing_user_search_view()` was slightly different from the code used by `search_view()` because `code_testing_user_search_view()` was not getting the name of the module implementing the search hooks as argument.

```
function code_testing_user_search_view($keys = '') {
  $info = FALSE;
  $redirect = FALSE;
  $keys = trim($keys);

  if (!$keys && !empty($_REQUEST['keys'])) {
    $keys = trim($_REQUEST['keys']);
  }

  $active_module_info = search_get_info();

  if (isset($active_module_info['user'])) {
    $info = $active_module_info['user'];
  }

  $results = array('#markup' => '');

  $conditions =  NULL;

  dpm($_POST);

  if (isset($info['conditions_callback']) && function_exists($info['conditions_callback'])) {
    $conditions = call_user_func($info['conditions_callback'], $keys);
  }

  if ($keys || !empty($conditions)) {
    $results = search_data($keys, $info['module'], $conditions);
  }

  $build['search_form'] = drupal_get_form('search_form', 'test/search', $keys, 'user');
  $build['search_results'] = $results;

  return $build;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well I'm not sure what the problem was, but after a bit of further digging into apachesolr_search I've come up with a work around which seems to do the trick:

```
$search_page = apachesolr_search_page_load('PAGE_ID');

module_load_include('inc', 'apachesolr_search', 'apachesolr_search.pages');
$build['search_form'] = drupal_get_form('apachesolr_search_custom_page_search_form', $search_page);
```

As kiamlaluno has noted in the comments it doesn't look like it's actually apachesolr_saerch causing this behaviour, but rather the core search module doing...something.

Hopefully this code will save someone the time in the future.

Comment: This worked for us. As an addition - you can use 'core_search' as the PAGE_ID for the default Apache Solr search page.

Comment: This worked great, I spent so much time on this already! Because my brain was a bit fried by the time I saw this, it took me a while to figure out the PAGE_ID - this is the ID of the custom search found in /admin/config/search/apachesolr/search-pages

Answer (score 0):

The Answer By Clive helped a lot. Thank you. I couldn't post this under that answer but it belongs there. A couple additions and a problem I had.  If you want to display two forms on the same page to two separate custom pages , I encountered a couple issues. Below is my custom php block where i display search forms to the image library and video library pages.
Problem 1: The forms had the same html id attribute. 2: The second form kept posting to the first search page. I finally fixed that by setting the #action to the forms. It defaulted to the current page the block was on.

Here is the working code. I add some custom classes, tweak the search prompt text,tweak the id , and tweak the action . Works great. Thanks .

```
<?php 
$search_page = apachesolr_search_page_load('image_library');
module_load_include('inc', 'apachesolr_search', 'apachesolr_search.pages'); 
$form = drupal_get_form('apachesolr_search_custom_page_search_form',$search_page);
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'pogoe-libraries-search-box';
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-message';
$form['basic']['keys']['#title'] = t('Search Images:');
$form['#id'] = "image-search-form";
$form['#action'] = "image-library"; // This defaulted to current page but still worked
print '<div>' . drupal_render($form) . '</div>';
?>

<?php      
$video_search_page = apachesolr_search_page_load('image_library_0');
$vform =drupal_get_form('apachesolr_search_custom_page_search_form',$video_search_page);
$vform['#attributes']['class'][] = 'pogoe-libraries-search-box';
$vform['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-message';
$vform['#id'] = "video-search-form";
$vform['basic']['keys']['#title'] = t('Search Videos:');
$vform['#action'] = "video-library"; // This defaulted to current page but always took me to the image-library search until I set this to video-library

print '<div>' . drupal_render($vform) . '</div>';
?>
```

Hope that helps